# delete parts of text with perl

Tags: perl, bash, shell, terminal

I have a text string like this in a perl script

```
PC i5-4570/4GB/500/DVD+/-RW Drive/-RW/FREE DOS/5Y Warranty
```

and want to delete almost everything within the / eg the above line would look like

```
PC i5-4570 FREE DOS/5Y Warranty
```

Can anyone please help ?

Thank you

Comment: You must say *exactly* what you want. *"almost everything within the /"* isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that specific string you can split by the '/' character and concatenate the pieces you want. Except you want to keep the last slash between DOS and 5Y. I'm not sure if this will be that helpful because it's not a generic solution, but this works for that string, and could work with similar patterns.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$str = "PC i5-4570/4GB/500/DVD+/-RW Drive/-RW/FREE DOS/5Y Warranty";
@splitStr = split('/',$str);
print $splitStr[0] . " " . $splitStr[6] . "/" . $splitStr[7];
```

outputs: PC i5-4570 FREE DOS/5Y Warranty

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do I have had to guess. I wonder if this helps? It splits the string on slashes, picks out the first and last two values, and passes them to `sprintf` for formatting.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'PC i5-4570/4GB/500/DVD+/-RW Drive/-RW/FREE DOS/5Y Warranty';

my @fields = split qr|/|, $string;

my $new_string = sprintf "%s %s/%s\n", @fields[0, -2, -1];

print $new_string, "\n";
```

**output**

```
PC i5-4570 FREE DOS/5Y Warranty
```

Answer (score 0):

and a one liner

```
echo "PC i5-4570/4GB/500/DVD+/-RW Drive/-RW/FREE DOS/5Y Warranty" | perl -p -i -e 's#(.*?)/.* (\w*/.*)$#$1 $2#g'
```